# How to find all the borrowers for a loan that have the Date-in before 15-Jan-10 and the Card number less than 400 in California and Alaska in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried this,

```
select b.BORROWER, l.DATEIN, br.BRANCHNAME
from BORROWER b, LOAN l, BRANCH br
where b.cardno=l.cardno
and l.branchid=br.branchid
and b.cardno <'300'
and l.datein <'15-Jan-15'
and (br.BRANCHNAME='California' or br.branchname='Alaska');
```

but showed nothing.
could any one help?

Comment: that's not a valid mysql time string. so whatever `datein` is, it'll be compared to your string using string rules, which means stuff like `15-Dec-15 < 15-Jan-15` is TRUE, because `D` comes before `J` in the alphabet. mysql's date-as-string format  is `yyyy-mm-hh`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.BORROWER, l.DATEIN, br.BRANCHNAME
from BORROWER b, LOAN l, BRANCH br
where b.cardno=l.cardno
and l.branchid=br.branchid
and b.cardno <'400'
and l.datein <'2015-01-10'
and (br.BRANCHNAME='California' or br.branchname='Alaska');
```

But it depends on the column type of datein. Is is a `Date`?

Comment: yap, the datein is a date.
I tried your way but still showing nothing, unless if i put the cardno<'400' it shows up the records. but i put less than 300 then nothing appeared.

Comment: Are you sure have records that match the conditions with `cardno < 300`?

Comment: Yeahhh..
i have a record which the card no is 111. it's the only card number that less than 300, but when put the query, it didn't show anything.

Comment: I just noticed you're pulling data from 3 different tables without `JOIN`ing them, si that by design?